# How to retrieve images from storage folder to view in blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to access images from storage folder to display in blade view. the images are in storage/app/photos.

I have run a command php artisan storage:link but still no luck showing images.

Here is my home controller

```
public function detailPro($id) {
    $products=DB::table('products_photos')
         ->join('products','products_photos.product_id','products.id')
         ->get();
         //dd($products);
    return view('front.product_detail', compact('products'));
}
```

here is my detail.blade.php

```
@foreach($products as $product)
   <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     </div>
     <img src="{{ url('storage/app/photos/'.$product->filename) }}" style="width:200px;" alt="">
   </div>
@endforeach
```

this is the logic of how i save images to db

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $product = Product::create($request->all());
    foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
        $filename = $photo->store('photos');
        ProductsPhoto::create([
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'filename' => $filename
        ]);
    }
    return 'Upload successful!';
}
```

the image doesn't appear and the url shown is this "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/app/photos/photos/xPNOQQTaTjPaKUClAHOxx7NEjsNLHguhVuAryZEg.jpeg".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem) and you can use `Storage::url('url')` if you have run `php artisan storage:link`

```
@foreach($products as $product)
   <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     </div>
     <img src="{{  Storage::url($product->filename) }}" style="width:200px;" alt="">
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Change your `store` method to

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $product = Product::create($request->all());
    foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
        $filename = $photo->store('public/photos');
        ProductsPhoto::create([
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'filename' => $filename
        ]);
    }
    return 'Upload successful!';
}
```

Comment: I did that but still not showing but the url has changed to ``http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/photos/xPNOQQTaTjPaKUClAHOxx7NEjsNLHguhVuAryZEg.jpeg`` @Salman

Comment: What is the path in the db you have stored for the image? and have you run the command `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: I updated the question to include the logic on how i save photos to db. Yes i did run the command and got this ``The [public/storage] directory has been linked.`` .  This is how the folder structure looks like https://imgur.com/a/cOlT0KN @Salman

Comment: can you try returning `return $filename = $photo->store('photos');` what this return?

Comment: It returns this `photos/iPmje1lWL07VddO2NqtWTGLbhforydCdpEwjpDJn.jpeg` @Salman

Comment: in blade file can you hardcode this `{{ Storage::url('photos/iPmje1lWL07VddO2NqtWTGLbhforydCdpEwjpDJn.jpeg')}` in `img` tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195863/discussion-between-salman-zafar-and-user11710915).

Answer (score 0):

1. Use filesystem 'public' configuration:

```
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
```

2. Run *php artisan storage:link*
3. Move you photos to directory 'storage/app/public/photos'
4. In detail.blade.php use

```
<img src="{{ url('/storage/'.$product->filename)}}" style="width:200px;" alt="">
```

And you gonna be fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

on your blade, try this:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
   <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     </div>
     <img src="{{ url('photos/'.$product->filename) }}" style="width:200px;" alt="">
   </div>
@endforeach
```